# How to stop auto rotate of shapes in Illustrator CS4?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I create a shape, like a rectangle, it starts out slightly rotated down to the right. This happens every time I start a new file and create a new rectangle. I don't see rotation in the appearance panel. When I look at the transform panel it lists rotation at zero. Yet all of my shapes tilt down and to the right.

How can I stop my shapes from auto rotating?

Comment: Does the Appearance Panel show any transform or rotation items?

Comment: Put a shim under your monitor to level it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Check if the constrain angle is set to 0

```
-> Preferences
```

else if its something wrong with your illustrator you can try writing a script to counter-rotate each shape a little (that is if all your shapes rotate the same amount) as a last resort. Or trying to install a new/different version of illustrator.

It should be the constrain angle though

Comment: That solved it! It was the constrain angle. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

at first go to preference (press ctrl+k) and change the value of "Constrain Angle" to 0 (zero). press ok button. see the image below:

[image: auto angle]

Comment: Welcome to GD.  Please correct the image to include a better screenshot of the dialog box because it may be downvoted and removed as spam since we can only see your name.  Please post quality answers to questions in the future